# Django in digitalocean

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean

With django running on digital ocean, how could i download a file that is on amazon web services and then manipulated. Is there a / temp folder or something, which frees that access for manipulation?

Answer (score 1):

The standard directory for temporary files on Unix-based systems is `/tmp`. From `man hier`:

> /tmp   This directory contains temporary files which may be deleted with no notice, such as by a regular job or at system boot up.

Your Django app can freely read and write files to the `/tmp` directory. However, I highly recommend using Python's builtin [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) module to take care of the details for you.